# Зеркальный текст в сафари IOS

Tags: css, css3, кроссбраузерность

Есть 3 картинки, при наведении на которые они поворачиваются, а на тыльной стороне появляется текст, на андроиде и пк все работает хорошо, а вот в сафари ios текст отзеркален по горизонтали: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как должно выглядеть: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daladn0/adh7fw49/1/

HTML :

```html
<section class="articles">
      <div class="title">Это интересно!</div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="articles__content">
          <div class="articles__left-column">
            <div class="articles__front"></div>
            <div class="articles__back">
              <p class="articles__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay overlay_5"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="articles__right-column">
            <div class="articles__item">
              <div class="articles__front"></div>
              <div class="articles__back">
               <p class="articles__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</p>
              </div>
              <div class="overlay overlay_5"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="articles__item">
              <div class="articles__front"></div>
              <div class="articles__back">
                <p class="articles__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</p>
              </div>
              <div class="overlay overlay_5"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

css:

```css
.articles {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  .title {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }

  &__content {
    width: 880px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  &__left-column {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 442px;
    perspective: 1000px;

    &:hover .articles__front {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
    &:hover .articles__back {transform: rotateY(360deg);z-index: 2;}

    .articles__front {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url('https://www.fotor.com/ru/loopBannerImg/indexBannerImg/banner-01.jpg') center (center/cover) no-repeat;
    }

    .articles__back,
    .articles__front {
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: .7s all;
    }

    .articles__back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: silver;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .articles__text {
      top: 70px;
      left: 50px;
      max-width: 400px;
      max-height: 245px;
    }
  }

  &__right-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .articles__text {
      top: 10px;
      left: 30px;
      max-width: 295px;
    }
  }

  &__item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    width: 345px;
    height: 192px;
    perspective: 1000px;

    &:nth-child(1) .articles__front{
      background: url('https://www.fotor.com/ru/loopBannerImg/indexBannerImg/banner-01.jpg') center (center/cover) no-repeat;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) .articles__front{
      background: url('https://www.fotor.com/ru/loopBannerImg/indexBannerImg/banner-01.jpg') center (center/cover) no-repeat;
    }

    &:hover .articles__front {transform: rotateY(180deg);}
    &:hover .articles__back {transform: rotateY(360deg);z-index: 2;}

    .articles__front {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .articles__back,
    .articles__front {
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: .7s all;
    }

    .articles__back {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: silver;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
  }

  &__text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 29px;
  }

  .overlay_5 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s all;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
Нужен префикс -webkit- и -moz-, не стоит полностью полагаться на препроцессоры в этом плане ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin надеюсь сейчас понятней

Comment: про развёрнутость наверное имелось в виду не просто какое-то свойство, а вообще описание подхода. не все могут понять зачем это свойство указано.

Comment: @daladn0 как раз таки нормально настроенный сборщик учтёт все префиксы и соберёт все нормально, без подобных казусов.